# Наезд на статус бар

Tags: android, android-sdk

Есть такой код:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sort_by_activity);
```

http://i7.5cm.ru/i/dT9l.png

Тулбар слишком близко находится к статус бару(при скрытии итемы вообще налегают друг на друга).

Смена `Gradle` версии и обновление библиотек до последних результатов не принесли. С разметкой так же пытался менять значения, никаких изменений.

Встречался ли кто-либо с подобным и буду рад услышать хотя-бы направление, в котором копать, ибо уже не представляю, с чем это может быть связано.

Все же укажу версию `Gradle - 2.14.1` и `Plugin version - 2.1.3`

Версии библиотек:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asgard.power"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.3.4'
```

UPD:

обернут в AppBarLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sortByCoordinator"
    android:parentActivityName=".ActivityMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/coordinatorBackground"
    android:clickable="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/sort_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/orange_gradient"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

UPD: Так выглядит с `CollapsingToolbar` по совету @ЮрийСПБ:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
                    app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Выдает `errorInflate`.

UPD:

Styles:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppDefault" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">6dp</item>

    </style>
    <style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Оберните тулбар в AppBarLayout

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил

Comment: И?.. Всё ещё не работает? Тогда попробуйте убрать из Toolbar и AppBarLayout `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло

Comment: А если только у AppBarLayout оставить этот атрибут? Или понизить либы до 23.3.0?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб оставлял только AppBarLayout, но не делал всего этого на 23.3.0
Каким образом вы определяете, для каких версий писать нужно?И как это отражается для пользователя?Я например понятия не имею, как оно себя вести на маршмеллоу будет.

Comment: Просто я помню, что на той версии оно, вроде, работало точно. Ещё у меня это работает и на 24.1.0. На 7 андроиде проблем не будет. Кстати, попробуйте ещё для CoordinatorLayout атрибут сей задать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб перепробовал во всех вариантах, сменил на 24.1.0 - не помогает

Comment: Попробуйте ещё этот тулюар назначить акшнбаром через setSupportActionBar()

Comment: @ЮрийСПб `private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setTitle("Power");
    }`
Он уже был назначен.

Comment: Скорее всего дело таки в `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` попробуйте его во всех комбинациях на всех вьюхах разметки. В т.ч. совсем без него.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пробовал

Comment: У меня примерно такое работает. Может вы в превью смотрите или InstantRun у вас включён и вы видите не настоящую разметку

Comment: @ЮрийСПб с выключенным инстант раном не тестил на fitsSystem, но  без него все равно так же.

Comment: Ну а вы попробуйте. Ну и вы не уточнили в превью неработающем смотрите или где.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб пробую на реальном устройстве Meizu M2 Note Lollipop 5.1, в дизайнер не смотрю практически, только совсем в редких случаях.

Comment: Ну... Выложите на gitHub весь проект, что ли... Посмотрю

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нельзя '=_=

Comment: Ну тогда последнее, что могу предложить - добавить вот это в телбар: `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб если разметку всего `Activity` (в котором неполадки) выложу - это будет иметь смысл?

Comment: Не думаю. Если советы выше не помогли - значит проблема или в невнимательности или запрятана глубоко. Попробуйте собрать простой проект с этой разметкой только. Так чтобы можно было склонировать и воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: Ещё мысль - оберните тулбар в CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил ответ, эррор инфлейт.

Comment: Мало инфы об ошибке. Решить вашу проблему можно только нсли минимальный её пример в виде проекта на github выложите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалось решить благодаря другу. Через стили:

```
  <style name="AppDefault" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/head_bottom_sheet_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/blue_gradient</item>
        <!-- Other -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
```

Отдаю награду @AlexVorobiev как первому догадавшемуся, что через флаги это не сработает.

Comment: Спасибо, рад что всё таки смогли решить проблему

Answer (score 2):

Помимо тега для прозрачного стиля статусбара можно использовать еще и следующий:
`<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

В связке с

`<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>`

Все работает отлично и ничто не наезжает на статус бар :)
По крайней мере у меня. 
И как посоветовал @ЮрийСПб оставь `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: Из универа приду, попробую. Если получится - узнаете первым :)

Comment: К сожалению, эти параметры в стилях уже указаны и даже с ними все равно не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте убрать следующую линию `w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`. У меня сработало
.

Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sortByCoordinator"
android:parentActivityName=".ActivityMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:clickable="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/sort_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        //w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    }


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

}

Styles

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: К сожалению, в этом случае статус бар становится черным, хоть и все нормализуется. Но смысл в том, чтобы градиент перенести на статус бар.

Comment: У меня получился тот эффект с градиентом но в этом решении мне пришлось изменить `colorPrimary` и `colorPrimaryDark` в `@android:color/transparent`.

Comment: так, у меня статусБар побелел. Сталкивались с этим?

Comment: Далее я изменил значение атрибута: `android:layout_height="match_parent"` в  -> `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` и удалил `w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`.

Comment: Нет, с android:background="@drawable/orange_gradient" сработало. Попробую посмотреть если чтото пропустил.

Comment: Вы были правы по поводу лаяут но лимитс, это было причиной наезжания.

Теперь только цвета градиента осталось поставить.

Comment: Я забыл `gradient` дрававле поставить: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="#ffcd80"
        android:endColor="#f29811"
        android:startColor="#f29811"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners
        android:radius="0dp"/>

</shape>`

Comment: скинул мои стили, может там что не так?Но пока что не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Пробовали `android:layout_marginTop="3dp"`?

Comment: пробовал, не помогло, сделав паддинг - частично лучше, но при скрытии тулбара - табы налезают.